# Arbitrarily nested arrays of integers into a flat array of integers java

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, nested

Can someone tell me how to flatten an array of arbitrarily nested arrays of integers into a flat array of integers?

E.g:

```
[[1,2,[3]],4] > [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: How does your datatype look like? `Object obs = new int[]{new int[]{...}}`?

Comment: answer is recursion (use a list for temporary storage)

Comment: "need some code" are you just serious ?

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.